# Evaluating $S(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sum_{r=1}^n(r)^k}$ for $k>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

$$S(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sum_{r=1}^n(r)^k}$$

I had found the original problem specifically for the cases $S(2)$, $S(3)$ and $S(5)$ which I did it in the following manner;

$$S(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sum_{r=1}^n(r)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{6}{{n(n+1)(2n+1)}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{6}{n}+\frac{6}{n+1}-\frac{24}{2n+1}\right)=18-24\,ln(2)$$

$$S(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sum_{r=1}^n(r)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4}{{n^2(n+1)^2}}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{2}{n+1}-\frac{2}{n}\right)=8\zeta(2)-12$$

$$S(5)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sum_{r=1}^n(r)^5}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{12}{{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{-12}{n^2}+\frac{-12}{(n+1)^2}
+\frac{48}{2n^2+2n-1}\right)=8\pi\sqrt3tan\left(\frac{\sqrt3 \pi}{2}\right)+60-4\pi^2$$

I tried searching for whether this can be generalized for any $k>0$, unfortunately couldn't find one.

I would be grateful to receive any work on how to solve $S(k)$.

---

Here's the work when evaluating for $k=5$, specifically $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{48}{2n^2+2n-1}$ was as follows;

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2+2n-1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}\right)$$

Using $$\psi(z)-\psi(z')=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+z'}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right)$$
$$\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\pi cot(\pi z)$$

$$S=1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}\left(\psi\left(\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1-\sqrt3}{2}\right)\right)=1+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}tan\left(\frac{\sqrt3 \pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Are you looking for a recurrence relation or an expression in terms of classical functions without sums? Because $S(k)$ in the given form is a valid expression to evaluate in my opinion.

Comment: @Jfischer was thinking an expression in terms of digamma function for large values of k

Comment: You could see the denominator as a polynomial which is a sum of monomials of power $k$ (of the form $x^k+y^k+...$) over $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is evaluated at $(1,2,...,n)$. If you manage to get a partial fraction decomposition of that one, then you might get somewhere. (This is effectively what you already did in the first cases)

Comment: Also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317336/42969

Comment: @MartinR thank you, the answers to that question are helpful

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate @Jfischer's comment, let us do it for $k=6$

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^6=\frac{1}{42} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^4+6 n^3-3 n+1\right)$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1{\sum_{r=1}^n r^6}=\frac{42}{n}+\frac{42}{n+1}-\frac{2688}{31 (2 n+1)}-\frac{126 \left(30 n^3+45 n^2-7 n-11\right)}{31 \left(3 n^4+6 n^3-3 n+1\right)}$$
Write the last term as
$$\frac{126 \left(30 n^3+45 n^2-7 n-11\right)}{31 \left(3 n^4+6 n^3-3 n+1\right)}=\frac{42 \left(30 n^3+45 n^2-7 n-11\right)}{31 (n-a) (n-b) (n-c) (n-d)}$$ where
$$(a,b,c,d)=-\frac 12 \pm \frac 12 \sqrt{3\pm\frac{2 i}{\sqrt{3}}} $$ and use partial fraction decomposition.

The partial sum (from $n=1$ to $n=p$) contains $14$ polygamma terms.

The result is
$$S(6)=\frac{21}{31} (66+60 \gamma -128 \log (2))+$$
$$\frac{21\left(15-7 i \sqrt{3}\right)}{31}  \left(\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3-\frac{2
   i}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)+\psi
  \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3-\frac{2
   i}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)\right)+$$

$$\frac{21\left(15+7 i \sqrt{3}\right)}{31}  \left(\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3+\frac{2
   i}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)+\psi
  \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3+\frac{2
   i}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)\right)$$

*I prefer not to think about the next.*

Comment: But how do we know if this does not simplify further ?

Comment: @mick. I do not know ! I spent about one hour trying to simplify it but I may be dumb. For sure, we can write  $$\sqrt{3-\frac{2 i}{\sqrt{3}}}=\sqrt[4]{\frac{31}{3}} \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right)\right)-i \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3
   \sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\right)$$ but I do not think that it helps much