# Limit of sequence involving reciprocal of the sum of the first squares

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ a sequence defined by $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1^2+2^2+\dots+k^2}.$ What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$?

My idea: $1^2+\dots+k^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}<\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}$. Thus
$$x_n>3\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=3\left(\frac 12 -\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}-\frac{1}{4}\right).$$
I couldn't continue any further. My assumption is that $x_n\to 2$ or something like that. Please help me solve it! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so. The first term of the sum is 1, so $x_n>1$ which forces the limit $\ge 1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think you may have missed that there are two sums here

Comment: What do you mean by two sums?

Comment: The comment was addressed to the other commenter. I mean that the denominator is a sum, but that denominator is in a fraction that is itself part of a sum.

Comment: Oh. I understood. Thank you

Comment: It should be noted that your inequality would be fine if the goal were simply to determine whether the sum converges, but does not seem like it would be helpful in bringing us towards an exact value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you properly wrote$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1^2+2^2+\dots+k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6}{k (k+1) (2 k+1)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition, as @Ben Grossmann already did it,
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{24}{2 k+1}$$
$$x_n=(6 H_n)+(6 H_{n+1}-6)-(12 H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}-24+24 \log (2))$$ Using the asymptotics
$$x_n=(18-24 \log (2))-\frac{3}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\frac{1}{k(k+1)(2k+1)} = \frac 1{k+1} + \frac 1k - \frac 4{2k+1}.
$$
So for instance, with $n = 10$, we end up with the sum
$$
\left(1 + 2\cdot \frac12 + \cdots +  2\cdot \frac 1{10} + \frac 1{11} \right) - 4\left(\frac 13 + \frac 15 + \cdots + \frac 1{21} \right) = \\
1 + 2 \left( \frac 12 - \frac 13 + \cdots -\frac 19 + \frac 1{10}\right) + \frac 1{11} - 4\left(\frac 1{11} + \frac 1{13} + \cdots + \frac 1{21} \right).
$$